# Which branch is to be checked out prior to integration using either of merge/merge squash/rebase?

Tags: git

I'm new to GIT and understand basics of git add, commit, branch, merge, squash merge, rebase.

However I am confused on the branch that needs to be checked out before integrating the branches (using either merge/squash merge/rebase). Assuming I have develop branch and feature1 branch. Feature1 branch contains say 2 commits since branching off Develop branch. And meanwhile develop branch has also got 2 commits after feature1 branch was created. Now I'm confused on how to decide which branch to checkout before doing either the merge/merge squash/rebase. I have come across some articles checking out develop and then doing git merge (or merge squash or rebase) feature1. Some say the other way where as some say do both ways. Any guidance that will help to to think through this clearly will be helpful.

For examples below I have given possible options.

Example 1 (merge):

Option 1:

git checkout develop

git merge feature1

Option 2:

git checkout feature1

git merge develop

got checkout develop

git merge feature1

Example 2 (rebase):

Option 1:

git checkout feature1

git rebase develop

git checkout develop

git merge feature1

Option 2:

git checkout feature1

git rebase develop

git checkout develop

git rebase feature1

Option 3:

git checkout develop

git rebase feature1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming based on the names that `develop` would be like your `master`, aka you build features in `feature1`, `feature2`, etc and it all comes together in `develop`.

In that case you would checkout `develop` and then when in `develop` run:

```
 git merge feature1
```

If there are any conflicts you will be prompted to resolve them (IntelliJ IDE has a really helpful feature for that). After resolving the conflicts you finalize the merge with another commit.

Rebasing is for a scenario where you want to add commits from a certain branch "on top of" commits from a different branch.

For example, you have the following commits in chronological order (descending):

```
    feature1 - commit D 
    develop - commit C
    feature1 - commit B
    develop - commit A
```

If you want to have the commits from `develop` applied to the code base before the ones from `feature1` you can rebase `feature1` on `develop`.

In that case you checkout feature1 and then run:

```
git rebase develop
```

You will also need to resolve conflicts if there are any, then you can `git add` the files again and `git rebase --continue` to finish the rebase.

After that the commit log will look like this:

```
    feature1 - commit D 
    feature1 - commit B
    develop - commit C
    develop - commit A
```

Even though commit B is older than commit C it will be applied after, because of the rebase.

You can then merge to `develop` to introduce feature1's commits there.

Comment: After I rebase the feature1 branch, you have said merge it with develop (in your last line,). Can I instead of merge, rebase feature1 after having develop branch checked out?

Comment: If you run `git rebase feature1` while having `develop` checked out you get the opposite effect. You would end up with the commits from `develop` "on top" off the commits from `feature1`. So in my example newest -> oldest would end up as C, A, D, B. I would advise AGAINST that, because generally a best practice is **not to rewrite history in your master branch**. Say another developer is meanwhile working on `feature2`. After you rebase `develop` on `feature1` his commit A & C would have different hashes now from the ones in `develop` because those would have been rewritten.

Comment: ... continuing comment above... If you work with several developers and several feature branches this can quickly turn into rebase hell. Plus, in some case you would actually need to reset `feature2` to master in order to get the old commits with the new hashes. Trust me, this is not a desirable situation. Generally the rule of thumb is that you want to rebase feature branches on master and not the other way around.

Comment: What I would advise is: 1. checkout feature1 2. run `git rebase develop` 3. checkout develop 4. run `git merge feature1`

Comment: Thanks. How about: git checkout feature1, git rebase develop, git checkout develop, git rebase feature1

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't. What would happen? First you rebase `feature1` on `develop`. So you end up with D,B,C,A on `feature1`. Then you checkout `develop` and rebase it on `feature1`. Now you also have D,B,C,A on `develop`. You will now have to `force push` this to `origin develop`. This might look like the same result as when you rebase `feature1` on `develop` and then merge it into `develop`, but the merge approach has 3 advantages: 1. You will not be rebasing `develop`. 2. You will not be force pushing `develop`. 3. You will see the merge commit

Comment: As I mentioned before you want to avoid rebasing your master branch as much as possible because rebasing is re-writing history. Therefore it introduces complexity and risk. You want to keep your master branch consistent throughout time because this is the branch that people are constantly branching off. Merging the rebased `feature1` into develop does that by avoiding a both a rebase and a force push on develop. Moreover, if you merge you get the merge commit, which adds legibility when at some point you are looking back to find when certain things were introduced.

Comment: Thanks for advise on merge vs rebase use case. I have now understood that we must checkout that Branch whose head we want to move ahead.

Comment: If we delete the feature branch after merging into develop branch, then don't we loose all history from the feature branch?